# Не получается перевести py в exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Имеется установленный плагин,pyinstaller(код простенькой программы,на заднем фоне):[image: Инсталлер.Ок,да?]

Захожу в папку с файлами и вожу cmd (чтобы в ручную не указывать путь до файла):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хоп,хей лалалей,выдаёт вот это ,хотя пайинсталлер скачан:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все дело в том, что pyinstaller не лежит в путях, где лежит, например, `pip`, решение этой проблемы уже давно валяется на просторах инета, вам следует поискать, и да, когда все получится, установите флаги -F и -w

Comment: Сори,за глупые вопросы ,но у меня питон ,среда разработки,и pip лежат на диске F , я посмотрел путь до pyinstaller`a он вообще на диске C(кроме пай инсталлера ,там ничего нет),пробовал удалять эту папку ,при скачке он просто создаёт новую папку и всё.Как изменить путь для установки?

Comment: нене, я не об этом

Comment: при установке питона, рекомендуется ставить галочку в _add to PATH_, тогда к нему будет доступ из cmd, та же ситуация и с `pip` и с `pyinstaller`, только вот я не помню как найти этот _PATH_, но дело в том, что в нем нет пути до pyinstaller..

Comment: а ну, прикрепите что выдаст команда `echo %PATH%`

Comment: "_при установке питона, рекомендуется ставить галочку в add to PATH, тогда к нему будет доступ из cmd, та же ситуация и с pip и с pyinstaller, только вот я не помню как найти этот PATH, но дело в том, что в нем нет пути до pyinstaller_ "  сейчас попробую снести и заново скачать Thonny

Comment: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Window
s;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Progra
m Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program File
s\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\HP\Common\HPDestPlgIn\;C:\Program Files\HP\
IdrsOCR_15.2.10.1114\;

Comment: @finally C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\P
rogram Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_86;C:\Program Files\HP\Comm
on\HPDestPlgIn\;C:\Users\Сергей\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\Lib\site-packages _это не вошло в тот комментарий_ .Коротко о том,что я сделал*1)снёс второй pip(он лежал от вижал студии ещё). 2)Переустановил Thonny в диск С. 3) Добавил путь к новому pip`y в PATH*
,но после того,как я удалил вижал студию у меня на команду pip выдаёт ошибку _"pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом._

Comment: @finally по-идее эта ошибка должна выскакивать только тогда,когда в PATH не прописан путь к pip.Крч единственное решение,которое я вижу,это снести винду ;)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102459/discussion-between-finally-and-mini-skill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перерыл весь интернет ,но в итоге помог этот совет:

> Попробуйте откатить версию pip до 18.1:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install pip==18.1
> ```
>
> потом установить pyinstaller:
>
> ```
> pip install pyinstaller
> ```
>
> потом обновить pip до последней версии:
>
> ```
> python -m pip install -U pip
> ```

Источник:https://python-scripts.com/question/28455

Comment: Если находите ответ где-то в интернете, желательно оставлять ссылку на источник.